# How to select multiple Features from multiple Layers in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, features, getfeatureinfo, select

Is there a way to select multiple features from multiple vector layers by using clickTolerance in click? 
I checked the documents of getFeature control and selectFeature control, seems not work in this way.

I know that it is possible to select multiple features by holding down Shift key. That's OK  in a desktop environment, but it's not desirable in mobile/tablets. So I'm looking for a different solution.

Answer (score 6):

This example should show you exactly what you need.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-multiple-features.html

Comment: thanks for your reply. but by clicking the selectFeature control can only select one feature at once, also there is no clickTolerance to set; by using box selection, user can select several features from multi layers. however, somehow in mobile devices it doesn't support clickout.

Comment: Of course you can select multi, just press shift.
As for clickTolerance that is an option you should be able to set at control creation. As I said that is an example you should copy it locally and customize it.
As for mobile support OpenLayers is currently making a considerable effort to implement touch functionality for mobile devices. I'm pretty sure it will be done when 2.11 is available.

Comment: first, clickTolerance is not an option in selectFeature control; second, i know in destop it's OK to select several features by pressing Shift or any other key, but it's not desirable in mobile/tablets; i was trying to integrate the config options of GetFeature Control which has clickTolerance and SelectFeature Control which enables the application in multi-layers, but failed...